# how to build a recursive stream for counting numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, bacon.js

I want to build a custom stream, counting pages recursively:

```
var pageStream = function(page, limit) {

  return Bacon.fromBinder(function(sink) {p
    if (page >= limit) {
      sink(new Bacon.End());
    } else {
      sink(Bacon.fromArray([page]));
      sink(new Bacon.Next(function() {
        return pageStream(page + 1, limit);
      }));
    }
  }).flatMapConcat(function(v) { return v; });
};


stream = pageStream(1, 5);

// If I use this code nothing is logged, why?
// stream.onEnd(function(v) {
//   console.log('done');
// });

stream.log();
```

I want `pageStream` to count up to `limit` and end the stream. It can count up to the limit, but it doesn't send the final `end` event.

Also if I listen to `stream.onEnd`, the stream doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task does't require recursion, but if you just want some recursion example, here you go:

```
var pageStream = function(page, limit) {
  if (page > limit) {
    return Bacon.never();
  } else {
    return Bacon.once(page).concat(pageStream(page + 1, limit));
  }
}
```

But again I wouldn't recommend this solution as for example for `pageStream(1, 5)` it generates:

```
Bacon.once(1).concat(
  Bacon.once(2).concat(
    Bacon.once(3).concat(
      Bacon.once(4).concat(
        Bacon.once(5).concat(
          Bacon.never())))));
```

Which will perform badly on large numbers.

Instead I would do something like this:

```
var pageStream = function(page, limit) {
  var arr = [];
  while (page <= limit) {
    arr.push(page);
    page++;
  }
  return Bacon.fromArray(arr);
}
```

---

> Also if I listen to stream.onEnd, the stream doesn't work at all.

This is classic Bacon pitfall with synchronous streams like `.fromArray` or `.once`: https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/wiki/FAQ#why-isnt-my-subscriber-called

To avoid this you can use `.sequentially()` instead of `.fromArray()`, and `.later()` instead of `.once()`:

```
var pageStream = function(page, limit) {
  var arr = [];
  while (page <= limit) {
    arr.push(page);
    page++;
  }
  return Bacon.sequentially(0, arr);
}

var pageStream = function(page, limit) {
  if (page > limit) {
    return Bacon.never();
  } else {
    return Bacon.later(0, page).concat(pageStream(page + 1, limit));
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a `limit` the recursion is infinite, I want to evaluate lazily, and use it with `take(limit)` eg: `infiniteCountStream().take(10)`

Comment: @user3995789 , take a look at this discussion https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/issues/521 maybe you could use the `looper` function from there